# Check maximum and minimum ylim and set_ylim for all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 7 subplots for each day of week. I want to have all of them the same size based on maximum range founded in plots and minimum range founded in plot.

I used something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2)

min_ylim = math.inf
max_ylim = 0

#...
#iterate over ax plots, draw a plot and check ylim
#...

plt.setp(ax, ylim=(min_ylim, max_ylim)) #apply to all subplots
```

Is there any simple method setting automatically for all plots the same y ax limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `sharey=True` to `subplots()` so that all subplots share the same y limits